# After taking image using camera, photo is not returned to my screen

Tags: android, cordova, camera, sencha-touch-2

I am trying capture the image using camera and putting in the screen in android. I am using sencha touch 2, phonegap for camera functionality. It is capturing the image but not displaying in the screen. 
Here is my code:

In dashboardpanel file:

```
{
        xtype : 'image',
        id : 'capturedimage',
        src : '',
        width : 60,
        height: 60,
        width : 200
 },
 {
        xtype : 'container',
        id : 'btncontainer',
        width : 120,
        layout : {
                   type : 'vbox'
              },
        items : [
        {
              xtype : 'button',
              height : 73,
              cls : 'capturebtn',
              id : 'capturebtn',
              width : 100
         },
         {
              xtype : 'button',
              height : 73,
              margin : '10 0 0 0',
              cls : 'choosephotobtn',
              id : 'selectphoto',
              width : 100
          } ]
   },
```

In Controller file::

```
onCaptureButtonTap: function(button, e, options) {
    /**
     *   phonegap Camera
     */

    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true });  

       function onFail(message) {
           alert('Failed because: ' + message);
       }

       function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
           // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
            console.log(imageData);

           // Get image handle
           //
           var smallImage = document.getElementById('capturedimage');

           // Unhide image elements
           //
           smallImage.style.display = 'block';

           // Show the captured photo
           // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
           //
           smallImage.src =  imageData;
         }

   }
```

But it is not coming. Can any one help me please..

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the `adb logcat` output??

Comment: No it is not giving any logcat error..

Comment: have you checked the last comment of @Simon to print the output of success

Comment: Now it is going inside onFail method

Comment: and what message it is getting??

Comment: It is failed. No Message is showing..

Comment: it is difficult to get the issue, i would suggest you ran the raw example and check it is working fine with your device/phonegap version or not - http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: 06-29 11:52:19.975: E/Web Console(9208): Uncaught ReferenceError: capturePhoto is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/MyController.js:97

Comment: this error i am getting in logcat

Comment: actually that means the function is `capturePhoto` is not getting initialized. You should open your main html file in browser (preferably chrome) and check in Console if there are any source/compile errors

Comment: in your html file there is a comment `<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->`, are you sure your written script is available when you run the code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to resolve this using the below link:

[Solution Link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?119274-phonegap-camera)

Answer (score 1):

It is because we now default to using a FILE_URI return type from getPicture. So now yo are just getting a url to the file instead off all the base64 encoded data. This is a much better approach as it does not use as much memory.  Change this line:

```
image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

to:

```
image.src = imageData;
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: I am no Sencha expert so to make sure the PG piece is working correctly do a console.log(imageData) in the onPhotoDataSuccess method so we can make sure it is getting called properly.

Answer (score 1):

dude !! try to set image on HTML img src ="" id="" something the you will get that image on screen

Comment: How to do that..i edited the code. When i am printing it in the console, it is giving me the base64 encoded image data. Like this:     07-23 12:25:55.015: I/Web Console(7215): content://media/external/images/media/125 at :899934341